# In-flight facilities information from Amadeus

Tags: amadeus

Is there any way of obtaining details of in-flight meals and entertainment through Amadeus' APIs? I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not provide anything like this for the moment. In the future, we plan to add more information regarding the amenities.